# CPU Utilization on UNIX

Tags: python, shell, unix, cpu

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of CPU% used for a particular process using Python/Shell, but so far nothing.

I have looked at a lot of questions here, but none could help me. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `top` good enough for your purposes?

Comment: This is a hard question to answer without context. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you hoping to figure out whether your program has balanced IO and CPU utilization optimally?  Are you trying to defend your program against some network engineer's accusation that it is a CPU hog?  When your tag mentions UNIX, which **nix variant do you mean?

Comment: @Eamorr : Can't use top. Been told not to.

Comment: @Ollie Jones: I am trying to make a system which would log the CPU utilization for my main program every minute. I'm using a RedHat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from shell, ps with the cp output format specifier:

```
ps -p <pid> -o cp
```

From python - see [psutil.Process.get_cpu_percent()](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation)

Comment: I'm not sure what command to execute for that.
I tried `ps -cp <pid>`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ps o "pid cp"
  PID  CP
 1609   0
 1813   0
 1851   0
 1885   0
 1896   0
 3164   0
21679   0
24019   2
```

If the process you're looking for might not be running as the same user etc, you can use `ps -eo "pid cp"` to show *all* processes on the system instead of just the default self-owned ones.

If you know a specific process ID, you could just do this:

```
$ ps -p 24019 -o "cp" --no-heading
  2
```

where `24019` is the process ID you want, and the result you get is a 3-character string (right-aligned, potentially 3-digit number).

Comment: For some reason, it's showing only 4 processes. And not the one I want to monitor.

Comment: ...probably because that process belongs to different user. Check updated answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

well, you can try to use the top command with "-b -n 1" and grab it's contents and than you can use cut or other tools to get what you need

NOTE: you  can add the -p option to limit to a particular process id